# Find multi-variable function that will make the statements true.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let x and y denote the concentrations of two proteins encoded by the genes A and B respectively. Let f(x, y) be the rate of change of the concentration of protein A. Find a formula for f(x, y), given the following assumptions: f(x, y) is the difference between the rate at which gene A produces protein A and the rate at which protein A degrades. ii. The concentration of protein A degrades at a rate equal to its concentration. iii. Gene A produces protein A at a rate inversely proportional to 1 + y. . Gene A produces protein A at a constant rate 3 when protein B is absent
Ok this is what iv'e got so far:

f(x,y)= Aproduced-Adegrade

Aproduced=1/(1+y)

Adegrade= x

f(x,y)=1/(1+y)-x
f(x,y) = (-yx-x)/(1+y)

f(x,0)=3 =-x

x= -3 This answer makes no sense as x is a concentration and ought to be positive right? If someone could highlight where I went wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)= A_{produced}-A_{degrade}$

$A_{produced}(y)=\frac{n}{1+y}$

$A_{produced}(0)=3$

$3=\frac{n}{1+0}$

$n=3$

$A_{degrade}= x$

$f(x,y)= \frac{3}{1+y}-x$